# Converting coordinates from Image to screen

Tags: coordinates, calibration

I'm working on a project where i detect finger movement in order to move the cursor on the screen so i have to translate the coordinates i get from the image to coordinates on the screen and move the cursor there.
**example:** the finger is detected on (128,127) i want to find the equivalent of that point on the screen. Image is (640 x 480) and the screen is (1366 x 768).

Can anybody help me with this. tried different methods but nothing is satisfying some of them i found on stack-overflow.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question doesn't provide much content, it would be useful if you can add some specifics, like what software you are using or comment what have you tried. Here is an [article on how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) that could help you to improve your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`ScreenX = event.X / PhoneWidth * ScreenWidth`

`ScreenY = event.Y / PhoneHeight * ScreenHeight`

Where `event.X` would be the X coordinate where the user touched the screen.

Comment: hi, i don't think this can work; i've tried it and it's always giving back (0,0).
Since 
event.X takes values from 0 to 640 
event.Y takes values from 0 to 480
phoneWidth * ScreenWidth is always >>> than event.X same goes for event.Y

Answer (score 0):

Try using a map function.
In c language it could look like this:

```
long map(long x, long in_min, long in_max, long out_min, long out_max)
{
  return (x - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min;
}
```